# Why does ingestion rate gradually falls in accumulo?

Tags: hadoop, bulkinsert, accumulo

I am trying to benchmark Accumulo on my 3 node test cluster. I have written a map reduce job that reads json documents from elastic-search cluster and ingests them in accumulo. When I start the Ingestion process, the ingestion rate is high but it gradually decreases and I get the following curve.
This curve has been consistent with all my attempts to ingest data.
[image: This is the curve that I am getting]

I want to know the reason behind this. I have pre-splitting enabled and have it optimized in accordance with my dataset.

I have Accumulo 1.6.1 and Hadoop 2.2 installed on the cluster.

Comment: That's a very curious graph. Normally, you'll see ingest oscillate around some central point (influenced by minor compactions). A steady downward rate seems to imply that the workload from the client isn't uniform. For example, new BatchWriters being created and not closed. Can you describe the map-reduce job in more detail?

Comment: Regarding the map reduce job, I have used mostly the code given in Accumulo examples(NGramIngest). I have made some customizations to it:
1. I have a map() function that reads key,value pairs from elastic-search(Key is the unique id and value is the JSON document). Then I get the required fields from the JSON object and rap everything in a mutation and emit it in the way similar to the code given in NgramIngest.
2. I have separate logic for pre-splitting the table. Hence I use that logic to pre-split the table.
3. There is no reduce() function.

Comment: I have also tried to add more spilts to this table that reduced the slope of this downward curve, but the shape remains the same.

Comment: If the servers see a decrease in throughput, you should also see that in your mappers. Over time, they'll also write less data to Accumulo. You should see if the amount of time your client takes to write data to Accumulo changes, or if your Mapper just isn't getting data fast enough. Otherwise, it might be ES, MapReduce or HDFS slowing down.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but this graph was due to some flaws in my pre-splitting criteria. Upon correcting that, I was able to get an oscillating curve as described by you. Correctly pre-splitting the table is very important I guess in accumulo Ingestion.

Comment: Yes, presplitting is important to get immediate ingest performance. Eventually the system would get to a desired state, but it would take a while since the default split threshold is 1GB.